# Error "The specified file was not found" when compiling c++ on notepad++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile c++ on notepad++ using the nppexec plugin and somehow, i get the "The specified file was not found" error. This is the script i'm using

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
g++ "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART) -march=native -O3
NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)
```

I installed MinGW ver 0.602 and i double checked the paths inside the system variables, there's nothing wrong with it. This is the piece of code i'm trying to compile and execute

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source could be the file name. Check the file's name again for spaces, special characters, things like that, it might fix your problem